# Using 2.4Ghz readers with passive tags and UHF readers with active tags

Tags: rfid

Can we use 2.4GHz RFID readers with passive tags and UHF readers with active tags? Or is it necessary that if we are using 2.4GHz reader then we must use active tags only? And similarly if we are using UHF reader then we must only use passive tag only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any "hybrid" reader. I've been working with UHF technology and (as a lesson) you shouldn't mix apples with pears. Both, active and passive tags work at different frequency.

The thing is that if you buy some UHF (865mhz - 928mhz) tags, and try to read them with your active interrogator you won't get any data read. The reason, the UHF tags won't be energize.

You could take a look at [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0050MBFE8) reader, it's pretty cheap and comes with a great API.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So basically when we talk about 2.4GHz readers, we are talking about active readers? It means there is no passive reader that works at 2.4Ghz?

Comment: That's correct. There are no passive tags whichs work at 2.4ghz.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:

1. No, you can't mix the technologies. The vast majority of passive UHF readers work on the gen2 protocol (ISO 18000-6C) and almost all active tags are proprietary and only work with the same manufacturer's readers. (yes, there is "dash 7" standard being developed for active tags & readers, but the answer still is "no" for active tags and passive readers, and vice-versa)
2. The aforementioned "dash 7" standard only works on the frequency of 433 MHz. So, just about any 2.4 GHz active reader will likely only work with the same manufacturer's active tags.